# Trigger RaisePropertyChanged from a different class

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, data-binding, inotifypropertychanged

I'm having a class called Mod :

```cs
class Mod : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private bool serverSideChecked;
    private string name;

    public bool ServerSideChecked
    {
        get => serverSideChecked;
        set
        {
            serverSideChecked = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("ServerSideChecked");
        }
    }

    public string Name
    {
        get => name;
        set
        {
            name = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("Name");
        }
    }
}
```

and another class called Profile that contains a list of Mods

```cs
class ServerProfileNew : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public int ServerModsChecked { get => Mods.Where(m => m.ServerSideChecked == true).Count(); }

    private List<Mod> _mods = new List<Mod>();
    public List<Mod> Mods
    {
        get => _mods;
        set
        {
            _mods = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("Mods");
        }
    }
}
```

Both classes implement INotifyPropertyChanged.
I would need `ServerModsChecked` in `Profile` to update whenever `ServerSideChecked` is changed in `Mod` to have the total count of checked mods in real time.
Is that possible and how to do it ?

Comment: In the `Mods` setter, attach a PropertyChanged event handler to each element in _mods. In that handler, call `RaisePropertyChanged("ServerModsChecked");`. Don't forget to detach the handler from the elements in the current `_mods` collection before.

Comment: I was actually trying to Attach PropertyChanged when adding Mods to the list but it triggered abount 4 times each... 
I'll try what you dais but I don't exactly understand what you mean by detach the handler from _mods

Comment: Please see the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `Mods` setter, attach a PropertyChanged event handler to each element in `_mods`. In that handler, call `RaisePropertyChanged("ServerModsChecked");`.

Don't forget to detach the handler from the elements in the current `_mods` collection before.

```
public List<Mod> Mods
{
    get => _mods;
    set
    {
        if (_mods != null)
        {
            _mods.ForEach(m => m.PropertyChanged -= ModCheckedChanged);
        }

        _mods = value;

        if (_mods != null)
        {
            _mods.ForEach(m => m.PropertyChanged += ModCheckedChanged);
        }

        RaisePropertyChanged("Mods");
    }
}

private void ModCheckedChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.PropertyName == nameof(Mod.ServerSideChecked))
    {
        RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(ServerModsChecked));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Turn `Mods` into a read-only `ObservableCollection<Mod>` property and attach and attach/detach event handlers to/from the `PropertyChanged` event for any `Mod` item that gets added or removed:

```
class ServerProfileNew : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public ServerProfileNew()
    {
        Mods.CollectionChanged += (s, e) => 
        {
            if (e.NewItems != null)
            {
                foreach (object item in e.NewItems)
                {
                    (item as INotifyPropertyChanged).PropertyChanged
                        += new PropertyChangedEventHandler(OnModPropertyChanged);
                }
            }

            if (e.OldItems != null)
            {
                foreach (object item in e.OldItems)
                {
                    (item as INotifyPropertyChanged).PropertyChanged
                        -= new PropertyChangedEventHandler(OnModPropertyChanged);
                }
            }

            RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(ServerModsChecked));
        };
    }

    private void OnModPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e) =>
        RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(ServerModsChecked));

    public int ServerModsChecked => Mods.Count(m => m.ServerSideChecked);

    public ObservableCollection<Mod> Mods { get; } = new ObservableCollection<Mod>();

    //...
}
```

This should make the `ServerModsChecked` property always in sync with the source collection.